# Code inside of if statement runs even when condition is false

Tags: javascript, if-statement

For some reason the user is prompted to answer even when the condition is not met.

```
function makePurchase()
{
    if (locationName !== "SpacePort"){alert("You are not at the SpacePort.S")}
    if (locationName === "SpacePort");{
        userBuys= prompt(userName + ". "+"What do you purchase? Lasers, Sensors, or Repair Ship.");
        {if(userBuys === "Lasers" && credits>=1000){lasers+10; credits-1000; alert("You have purchased lasers.")};
        if(userBuys === "Sensors"){};if(userBuys === "Repair Ship"){shipDamage=0}}
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you allergic to white space in your code?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is due to a typo.

Comment: I have white space set to be stripped when code is saved

Comment: You shouldn't strip until you deploy, you should keep unstripped code in your repository.

Comment: You should consider running your code through a linter like [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) or [JSHint](http://jshint.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if (locationName === "SpacePort");
```

there is a semicolon that shouldn't be there…

The semicolon signifies the "end of the `if` statement" . The code in `{}` that follows is not associated with the `if`. Leave out the semicolon and it will behave as expected.

As was mentioned in the comments above, good formatting of code (including carriage returns, indentations, etc) can help prevent these kinds of errors. It's one thing to squish code once you are sending it into the big wide world - but while you are still fiddling, give yourself space, long variable names, and consistent indentation. The more complex your code, the more you'll wish you did.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, the issue is now resolved because of you advice.

Comment: what about the up vote on the previous 3?

Answer (score 3):

Thats because you are closing `if` condition, remove `;` after

replace

`if (locationName === "SpacePort");`

with

```
if (locationName === "SpacePort")
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon after the if statement:

```
 if (locationName === "SpacePort");
```

should be

```
 if (locationName === "SpacePort")
```

Comment: Is there an echo here? Why would someone upvote an answer that duplicates the 3 previous answers?

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo. You have a semicolon after your if statement for locationName === "SpacePort". Should be:

```
function makePurchase()
{
    if (locationName !== "SpacePort"){alert("You are not at the SpacePort.S")}
    if (locationName === "SpacePort"){
        userBuys= prompt(userName + ". "+"What do you purchase? Lasers, Sensors, or Repair Ship.");
        {if(userBuys === "Lasers" && credits>=1000){lasers+10; credits-1000; alert("You have purchased lasers.")};
        if(userBuys === "Sensors"){};if(userBuys === "Repair Ship"){shipDamage=0}}
    }
}
```